# Ruby on Rails Tutorial - 5.26 - Sublime Text "Unable to Save" new file "spec/support/utilities.rb"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Sublime Text 2 while following Michael Hartl's *Ruby on Rails Tutorial*.

The specific portion of the tutorial to which I am referring can be found at http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial (ctrl+F "Listing 5.26").

I am able to create the spec/support file. However, when trying to create the spec/support/utilities.rb file, I receive the message "Unable to save ~/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/support/utilities.rb".

Does anyone know why this might be?

Someone on the Sublime Text forum seems to have had the exact same problem: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8570&p=36922#p36922

Comment: "How do I save a file" is really not a question suitable for a website for professional programmers. Voted to migrate to [SuperUser](http://SuperUser.Com/). Also, this question has absolutely nothing to do with Ruby and/or Ruby on Rails.

Comment: I'm a proffessional programmer and found this somewhat helpful as I'm just now getting into rails, and under mavericks 10.9 am having permission problems.  Not ones I've experienced with laravel or node.

Answer (score 3):

This issue sounds like it's a result of incorrect permissions or ownership of the folder. Change directories (`cd`) so you're outside of the folder where you're creating the .rb file and type:

```
ls -l
```

This terminal command lists the permissions attached to all files/folders in that directory. If "root" is listed as the folder owner, change its owner by typing:

```
sudo chown YOUR_COMP_USER_NAME FOLDER_NAME/
```

You should now be able to save files from inside that folder.

Answer (score 1):

To diagnose this, first find out if it's an issue in Sublime or your file system:

- Does that file already exist? Try looking for it on your file system (not using Sublime).
- Verify that you have permission to write to that file. Use "ls -la" on the command line to show the file permissions.
- Are you able to create and/or save that file using any different editor, for example TextMate, or Notepad?

Answer (score 1):

The following sublime plugin fixed the `Unable to save...` bug
https://gist.github.com/3779601

Answer (score 0):

The folder spec/support doesn't exist, and sublime won't create the missing folder, so it errors.

You just need to make the spec/support folder , then sublime will save the file.

I also highly recommend installing the AdvancedNewFile plugin [( Video of it action thanks to Jeffrey Way and NetTuts+ )](https://tutsplus.com/lesson/lightning-fast-folder-and-file-creation/) , which you can grab straight from Package Control.
It creates files, parent folders if needed, and if you try to create a file that already exists, it opens it instead.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you are trying to create the file within a directory that does not currently exist. For ex. I was unable to save

~/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb

via the "subl" command from the Terminal because I was missing /shared/ folder. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

so @knice almost had it,  I ran into the same problem with permission when starting my first rails project on mavericks.

as mentioned if you run ls -l you'll see your folder / files listed with their permissions

I solved this by changing ownership recursively with the following command from outside my project directory

```
sudo chown -Rv <your_username> <your_path_and_foldername>
```

for example  if you're in your folder in terminal you should `cd ..` and then

```
sudo chown -Rv username ruby_proj/
```

the `-R` is for recursive meaning it will apply to all files and folder contained within the folder you specified, and the v after just produces verbose output, showing you which folder and file permissions have been changed.

Hope that helps someone else.

Comment: you can also pass the `whoami` shell command instead of the putting in your username.